# Filter a table and display only the <td> it matches

Tags: javascript

I've currently got a table of images:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td><img src="img1.png">Image 1</td>
    <td><img src="img2.png">Image 2</td>
    <td><img src="img3.png">Image 3</td>
    <td><img src="img4.png">Image 4</td>
    <td><img src="img5.png">Image 5</td>
    <td><img src="img6.png">Image 6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><img src="img7.png">Image 7</td>
    <td><img src="img8.png">Image 8</td>
    <td><img src="img9.png">Image 9</td>
    <td><img src="img10.png">Image 10</td>
    <td><img src="img11.png">Image 11</td>
    <td><img src="img12.png">Image 12</td>
</tr></table>
```

And wish to put a searchable filter on them. I've tried a couple of Javascript filters on the internet, however it filters the entire row rather than just the image(s) I wanted. Any ideas? Many thanks.

Comment: What's the filter criteria? The cell text? Are you using any lib.... jquery?

Comment: Yes, the cell text. Not currently using any library however if it makes it easier then I can. Thank you

Comment: jQuery makes it a lot easier indeed

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty. I've set up an input, when text is entered it is using jQuery to filter for any divs that contain the text entered. When no text is entered, nothing is highlighted.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#filter-string").on("keyup", function() {
    var filterBy = $(this).val();
    $("td").removeClass("filtered").show();
    if (filterBy.length > 0) {
      $("td").hide();
      $("td:contains('" + filterBy + "')")
        .addClass("filtered").show();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.filtered {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="img1.png">Image 1</td>
    <td><img src="img2.png">Image 2</td>
    <td><img src="img3.png">Image 3</td>
    <td><img src="img4.png">Image 4</td>
    <td><img src="img5.png">Image 5</td>
    <td><img src="img6.png">Image 6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="img7.png">Image 7</td>
    <td><img src="img8.png">Image 8</td>
    <td><img src="img9.png">Image 9</td>
    <td><img src="img10.png">Image 10</td>
    <td><img src="img11.png">Image 11</td>
    <td><img src="img12.png">Image 12</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div class="filter-pane">
  <label for="filter-string">Enter filter</label>
  <input type="text" id="filter-string" />
</div>
```

Per your request, it now hides everything but elements that match the input string. With NO input string, everything shows.

Comment: Thanks for the code Snowmonkey. I've got it working but in stead of highlighting, it removes the result, however if you search for 'Image 1' it will remove Image 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, however the gap is still there. Is there anyway to make the photos move up as they are being removed by the filter? Hope this make sense, many thanks.

Comment: @TCampbell,  Try that on for size.

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you mean by for size. Are you able to provide another example? Thanks.

Comment: @TCampbell I edited the above code to do the hide/show of elements that don't match. I mean, re-run the above code and see if that's what you're looking for. lazy slang bites me again.

Comment: T_Campbell, you need to use divs instead of a table and tds for automatic rearrangement of images + labels.

Comment: Good point, @Adder. It would definitely improve the code. TCampbell, I can make that change if you'd like. You'd get the same visual result from the CSS

Comment: Yes thank you, that makes much more sense using divs. Got it working now, many thanks for all who helped out.

Answer (score 0):

```
// For instance filtering the 7th image
var filterCriteriaStr = 7;
$('td').not(':contains('+filterCriteriaStr+')').hide();
$('td').filter(':contains('+filterCriteriaStr+')').show();
```

Here's working example: https://jsfiddle.net/9gt3t2jk/1/

Comment: Yeah , probably but that is a special request :)

Comment: Sorry, @kidwon, that was a cross-brainfart. Working on a slide/show carousel at the same time. My bad!